# AVAssetReaderTrackOutput's copyNextSampleBuffer returns CMSampleBufferRef with wrong size

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have a piece of code that reads a video AVAssetTrack's sampleBuffer:

```
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

NSDictionary *pixelBufferAttributes = @{
    (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
};

AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *assetReaderTrackOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:videoTrack
                                                               outputSettings:pixelBufferAttributes];

NSError *assetReaderCreationError = nil;

AVAssetReader *assetReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset
                                                  error:&assetReaderCreationError];

[assetReader addOutput:assetReaderTrackOutput];

[assetReader startReading];

while (assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) {
    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [assetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

    // Some OpenGL operations here
}

// and other operations here, too
```

The code above works normally for almost all videos, but there's a video that always crashed. Upon inspection, I found that the `CMSampleBufferRef` result has different size than the real asset.

When printed out from the debugger, `sampleBuffer` has dimension of `848 x 480`, whereas the real asset has dimension of `1154.88720703125 x 480`.

I tried to search about the cause of this issue, but found none. Do any of you have any insight about this? Any comments or input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "real asset" is reporting the scaled dimensions of the video in points where the video is stretched horizontally from its pixel width of 848.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the insight! I'll try to check it once more, and get back to you again. Thanks! :)

Comment: I found out that the `naturalSize` from the `videoTrack` object returns `1154.88720703125 x 480`, too. Does that mean `AVAssetTrack` returns the horizontally stretched size instead of the real one?

Comment: Turns out I can retrieve the pixel width (in this case, the `848` one) using `AVAssetTrack`'s `formatDescriptions`. All I need to do is cast `formatDescriptions` first object to `CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef`, and pass it to `CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions` function.

Once again, thanks Kevin! :D